# Matplotlib arrow positioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I noticed that the positioning of `pyplot.arrow` (white) is odd.

I misused `pyplot.quiver` (black) as reference:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Z = np.random.random((50,50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.9,5.9))

im = ax.imshow(Z, origin='lower', cmap='coolwarm')

ax.hlines( 10 , 0, Z.shape[0]-1, color='black', ls='-', lw=1, alpha=.3)
ax.hlines( 40 , 0, Z.shape[0]-1, color='black', ls='-', lw=1, alpha=.3)

ax.arrow( 10, 10, 0, 30, color='white', head_width=1, length_includes_head=True)
ax.quiver(20, 10, 0, 30, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)

ax.grid(visible=False)
fig.savefig('arrows.jpg', dpi=300)
```

[image: plot]

The head overshoots considerably ...

[image: arrow heads]

... and the tail is actually off as well.

[image: arrow tails]

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I wonder if that is caused by the line width of the patch artist. Does the accuracy improve if you make the figure very large or zoom in on the arrow tip?

Comment: Based on a few experiments with different zooms, my suspicion was correct. You get an accurate arrow by setting the `linewidth=0., width=0.3`.

Comment: Basically, the arrow is a polygon patch artist. Patches consist of a filled area circumscribed by a line. The path of the patch has the correct coordinates. However, the line is centered on that path. So if the line has any thickness, the effective size of the arrow is increased.

Comment: Awesome! That fixes it! Thank you very much!